# how to handle event of Dropdown menu using anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Dropdowm menu created in bootstrap using Anchor tag. How to handle the event of that menu.

I gone through some websites they given the events like,

->hide.bs.dropdown
->show.bs.dropdown

Please anybody explain with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Example will explain.**

1. `show.bs.dropdown` - This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
2. `shown.bs.dropdown` - This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).
3. `hide.bs.dropdown` - This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
4. `hidden.bs.dropdown` - This event is fired when the dropdown has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).

[Get More reference form Offcial Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

```js
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    console.log("Dropdown show");
  });

$('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
  console.log("Dropdown shown (wait for CSS Transition)");
});

$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  console.log("Dropown hide");
});

$('#myDropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
  console.log("Dropdown hidden (wait for CSS Transition)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown trigger
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working

Comment: @Abi You're welcome. kindly mark as appropriate answer.